# Why was there no election since 2011?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

I wonder why there was no moderator election since 2011?
See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/election

Don't get me wrong, I don't think the current moderators do a bad job or so. It's just that in other communities like askubuntu or stackoverflow there was an election at least once a year. See https://askubuntu.com/election/ and https://stackoverflow.com/election

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Moderators do not have a fixed term. They remain moderators until they choose to step away. Therefore moderator elections are only held when moderators have left, or when a site has grown so that more moderators are needed.

The 3 moderators elected in 2011 are still active, and while the site has grown, it is a remarkably drama-free site for Stack Exchange, so 3 moderators are still enough. There hasn't been any need to conduct a new election.

Comment: ^ our might as well be a moderator has spoken. We don't need to hold elections we just need to stick a diamond next to his name. Lol

Comment: @xenoterracide: If you and the other mods _do_ need some help, don't hesitate to contact one of the community managers.  (Me, for instance. ;)  I completely agree with Gilles; it's nice to see a site running so smoothly.

Comment: I agree with Gilles, this site is the most pleasant of all the SE sites I've frequented! Besides we have a very active community that does a lot of the care and feeding and there is rarely an issue that needs a moderators help.